# Meteor jstree - How to get children files?

Tags: jquery, file, dynamic, meteor, jstree

In Meteor, I am using jstree plugin for file management system. I want to populate the dynamic files for jstree structure. Right now uploaded files are populating as a folders inside the "root" folder.

```
<div id="jstree_demo"></div>

$('#jstree_demo').jstree({
                            "core": {
                                "animation": 0,
                                "check_callback": true,
                                "themes": {
                                    "stripes": true
                                },
                                "data" : [
                                    {
                                        "text" : "Home",                      
                                        "children" : Uploads.find().fetch(),

                                        "type" : "root"
                                    }]
                                },
                            "types": {
                                "#": {
                                    "max_children": 5,
                                    "max_depth": 10,
                                    "valid_children": ["root"]
                                },
                                "root": {
                                    "icon": "/static/3.1.1/assets/images/tree_icon.png",
                                    "valid_children": ["default"]
                                },
                                "default": {
                                    "valid_children": ["default", "file"]
                                },
                                "file": {
                                    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-file",
                                    "valid_children": [],
                                    "type": "file"
                                }
                            },
                            "plugins": ["contextmenu", "dnd", "search", "state", "types", "wholerow"]
  });
```

Here, `Uploads.find().fetch()` is the function to generate dynamic files structure. How can I create files instead of folders using this function? Also I need to add "state" option(disabled/enabled) to this, please help me to accomplish this task.